# Win10 / Ubuntu dual boot on separate HDD/SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

On my laptop Win10 was installed on SSD. I setup HDD and install Ubuntu on it. EFI partition is on SSD. First boot - ok. Next boot - grub command line on black screen. After that I reboot, enter BIOS setup, then "Save and exit". Booting ok. Next reboot - again black screen. I.e. for booting I need to enter BIOS setup and click "Save and exit". Without this operation grub doesn't boot.
I'm confused a little...

Comment: Somethings missing here. I at least am confused. Are you saying that you are making no changes in the BIOS but yet Saving and exiting it has an impact? What bug riddled BIOS version in what model laptop?

Comment: In addition to Elder Geek's questions. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? It is as if you are switching from UEFI to BIOS and vice-versa? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Did you partition HDD with gpt? http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Sure. Win10 and Ubuntu in UEFI mode but Secure boot disabled (I work with kernel drivers).

Comment: Both HDDs are in GPT. UEFI last version. Laptop - Lenovo G50-45, A8 and R5.I'm confused too

Comment: P.S. the same issue with Fedora 24. No ideas...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Given your configuration, your boot files are spread across two physical disks -- the `grubx64.efi` binary is on the SSD and its configuration files and the Linux kernel are on the HDD. If the HDD took longer to be detected than the SSD, the symptoms you report might result. Moving the GRUB configuration files to the SSD might fix the problem. You can do this by creating a separate `/boot` partition on the SSD. Alternatively, you could try using my [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which supports a `scan_delay` option that may be useful.

Comment: Voting to reopen so @RodSmith can give a better answer and it's clear what the problem is...